# How to write REST web service in PHP for Android application backend?

Tags: php, mysql, rest

Currently, I am developing an Android application with involves client server architecture. It is said to me that I have to write REST web service in PHP for back end communication. At that time I didn't know about RESTful architecture and etc..

In last 3 days, I learned much about `REST` web services and tried many tutorials. Then, I tried some code from tutorials and from SO. What I have tried so far is as follows:

I have three php files, a database named `xyz` and table named `user_accounts` with basic user details in phpmyadmin. And I have installed Advanced REST client on my browser. All code is in `WWW` directory of `WAMP server` under folder named `my project`.  So, let me show some code:

**1. db_connect.php**

```
 <?php

            define("SERVER", '127.0.0.1');
            define("USER", 'root');
            define("PASSWORD", '');
            define("DB", 'xyz');


            $con = new mysqli(SERVER,USER,PASSWORD,DB);

            if ($con->connect_errno){
                die("Database Connection Failed");
                exit();

            }
```

In second file I have a function named `adduser` for adding user records into the database  :
  **index.php :**

```
    <?php
            require_once('db_connect.php');

           $response = array();

           $result = "";


           function adduser($firstname, $lastname, $email, $password) {


            global $app;

            $req = $app->request();

            $firstname= $req->params['firstname'];

            $lastname= $req->params['lastname'];

            $email = $req->params['email'];

             $password = $req->params['password'];


    $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO user_accounts (first_name,last_name,email,password)VALUES (?,?,?,?)");

                        $stmt->bind_param('ssss', $firstname, $lastname, $email, $password); 

                        $stmt->execute();

                        $result = $stmt->close();


        }

                if($result){

                          $response["success"] = 1;

                          $response["message"] = "account successfully created.";

                          echo json_encode($response);

                }

                else{

                     $response["success"] = 0;

                     $response["message"] = "An error occurred during registration.";

                     echo json_encode($response);
                 }



            ?>
```

When I test it using advanced REST client by giving url :

```
http://127.0.0.1/my project/index.php/adduser
```

and method `POST` and parameters:

```
firstname=somename&lastname=name&email=a@b.gmail.com&password=101010
```

It shows following response:

```
{"success":0,"message":"An error occurred during registration."}
```

I can not identify where the error is. I am new to this. Please help if anything wrong.

Comment: Check : http://androidexample.com/Restful_Webservice_Call_And_Get_And_Parse_JSON_Data-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=101&aaid=123

Comment: Please narrow down your problem and why is there a space in your URL ?

Comment: @HareshChhelana the example you linked has nothing to do with database.

Comment: @Raptor in 'my project'?

Comment: Where are you calling adduser()?

Comment: @SajibAcharya in url.

Comment: I really do not understand what you do in your function. You have 4 parameters for your function, but do not use them? So why are they there?

Comment: Is this your full code for `index.php`? Moreover, if you are using `POST` method, your `firstname=somename&lastname=name&email=a@b.gmail.com&password=101010` does not seem right. This is for a `GET` method. And for a `POST` method you get the data in your php code in the form `$_POST['firstname']`, `$_POST['lastname']` etc.

Comment: @SajibAcharya No, because this is REST!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your should try this:

```
$affected_rows = $stmt->rowCount();
```

### Update:

then check if row count is greater than 0.

```
<?php
        require_once('db_connect.php');

       $response = array();

       $result = "";


function adduser($firstname, $lastname, $email, $password) {
    global $app;
    $req = $app->request();
    $firstname= $req->params['firstname'];
    $lastname= $req->params['lastname'];
    $email = $req->params['email'];
    $password = $req->params['password'];

    $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO user_accounts (first_name,last_name,email,password)VALUES (?,?,?,?)");

    $stmt->bind_param('ssss', $firstname, $lastname, $email, $password); 
    $stmt->execute();

    return $stmt->rowCount();
}

$adduser = addUser($firstname, $lastname, $email, $password);

if($adduser > 0){
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "account successfully created.";

    echo json_encode($response);
} else{
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "An error occurred during registration.";

    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

Comment: where to try? I mean i am new to php